# how to retrieve the value from nested object arrays angular

Tags: html, arrays, angular, ngfor

I have an array of objects with nested arrays as shown below. How can I print the nested array values in a table using ngFor.
The array looks as follows:
[image]

I am using a table to print this values so I can export the table to Excel sheet.

The table looks as follows:

```html
   <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Hours</th>
                    <th>Dates</th>
                    <th>Project Codes</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="tbody" *ngFor="let value of array; let i = index">
                <tr *ngFor="let item of array[i].item; let dateValue of array[i].datesArray; let h of array[i].hours">
                    <td>{{h}}</td>
                    <td>{{dateValue}}</td>
                    <td>{{value.projectCodeInput}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I am using multiple arrays on single tag in ngFor like this:
{*ngFor="let item of array[i].item; let dateValue of array[i].datesArray; let h of array[i].hours"}
**I know this is wrong way**, but somehow the hours prints in the output in both places overriding the dateValue in second column.

Is there a way to print the values from hours, dateValue array in the same element(TABLE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having multiple inputs to the `*ngFor` directive, you could move the `let i=index` to the inner loop and use it to get the values.

I assume all the sub-arrays will always be of equal length i.e. `hours`, `datesArray` and `item` array will always be of equal length.

If you wish to span the `projectCodeInput` property across multiple rows since it'll be the same for each element of the parent array, you could do so using `[attr.rowspan]` property and `first` local variable of the `*ngFor` directive. The check is to make sure the span element is rendered only once for the loop.

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Hours</th>
      <th>Dates</th>
      <th>Project Codes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tbody" *ngFor="let element of arr">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of element.item; let i=index; let f=first">
      <td>{{element.hours[i]}}</td>
      <td>{{element.datesArray[i]}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="f" [attr.rowspan]="element.item.length">{{element.projectCodeInput}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jh6n4u?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the index of the inner loop and get the values with this index `z`:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Hours</th>
            <th>Dates</th>
            <th>Project Codes</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody" *ngFor="let value of array; let i = index">
        <tr *ngFor="let item of array[i].item; let z = index">
            <td>{{array[i].hours[z]}}</td>
            <td>{{array[i].datesArray[z]}}</td>
            <td>{{value.projectCodeInput}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```